# Linux single key presses triggering multiple-key combinations

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, xserver

I understand that new keyboards can be ordered online, but now that this problem has proven to be hard I am completely fascinated by it.

Many old laptop keyboards as they wear develop consistent shorts which cause multiple keys to react when a single key is pressed. For example, on my little sister's computer if you press "r" the system outputs "vr", "i" outputs ",i" and so-on.

Assuming the user is not a vim/emacs power user, the keyboard still seems salvageable. It seems that if the keyboard driver was changed so that pressing the "r" key resulted in the computer accepting "backspace r" the "v" would disappear and not be such a hassle anymore.

Xmodmap XKB and other systems seem to assume that each single key depression will result in a single command. Does anybody understand the missing link where more than one character can come from a single keypress? There seem to be many places in the stack where this can be pulled off, but none of them are particularly clearly documented. Another fun fact is that you can't force this in the ubuntu keyboard shortcuts editor, ubuntu will stop you from entering the changes there under the premise that "this will make it impossible to type."

Hacking around in xev shows that the computer believes that when you hit and release 'r' that it gets a keypress event for 'v' then a keypress event for 'r' then a keyrelease event for 'v' then one for 'r'. If you could change the configuration to ignore a first keypress if there is no corresponding key release before the next key is pressed, that would work too.

Comment: I would do that in the X server (The kernel should not be responsible for hacks like these). Writing drivers is simple nowadays. But i suspect that it won't helps much in your case. Maybe you should start writing a X Client to test your theories.

Comment: Hacks like this shouldn't be in the kernel, but if I get it in low enough in the system I can make stuff like vim usable again. Even if it isn't the "right" place I am looking for the easiest place.

Comment: Are you certain that the keyboard's behavior is still unambiguous? For instance, if `r` generates `vr`, does `v` generate something distinct from that?

Comment: yes, v generates v. From xev, pressing r generates a v downpress, an r downpress, a v release then an r release. V simply generates a v downpress and a v release

Comment: @KatyLevinson: I forgot the kernel has support for fake input devices using `uinput`. So you can read events from your actual device, frobnicate it and write the resulting events to that fake input.

Comment: I wish this was possible. Not to fix old, broken keyboards, but to create useful shortcuts. For example, a key that outputs thin space + em dash + thin space. Or one that outputs left parenthesis + right parenthesis + arrow left (to surround the cursor with parenthesis). I call that "surrounding". I'd find that super convenient for lots of characters: ( { [ < ' " `